# Java pass and construct class as function argument

Tags: java

I was using a library called Mallet. It is by far the most complicated Java Library I have ever used. They provide tutorials and code template and I was trying to understand it. However, I came across this line of code:

```
TransducerEvaluator evaluator = new MultiSegmentationEvaluator(
                new InstanceList[]{trainingData, testingData},
                new String[]{"train", "test"}, labels, labels) {
              @Override
              public boolean precondition(TransducerTrainer tt) {
                // evaluate model every 5 training iterations
                return tt.getIteration() % 5 == 0;
              }
         };
```

Please don't pay too much attention on the term "transducer". What is passed into this function? Two classes? What is this `new String[]{}`? I am just very very confused with this syntax as I have never seen it before.

This is the code for this method:

```
public MultiSegmentationEvaluator (InstanceList[] instanceLists, String[] instanceListDescriptions,
            Object[] segmentStartTags, Object[] segmentContinueTags)
```

Can someone tell me what this weird construct is?

Comment: What is `new`? What is `String`? What is `[]` associated with?

Comment: Sweet, anonymous classes.  IMO these should be avoided like the plague--although this _is_ simple enough to where I can see the justification for it.

Answer (score 1):

This construct does several things:

- Creates a subclass of `MultiSegmentationEvaluator` without giving it a name
- Provides an override of the `precondition(TransducerTrainer tt)` method
- Instantiates the newly defined anonymous class by passing two string arrays and then `labels` to the constructor that takes four parameters.
- Assigns the newly created instance to the `evaluator` variable.

The code uses the anonymous class feature of Java - a very handy tool for situations when you have to subclass or implement an interface, but the class that you define is used in only one spot in your program.

Comment: I can see it now...gee this is crazy. Is there any tutorial or proper documentation on this? It's definitely not under "subclass".

Comment: @WindDweller [Here is a link to the tutorial on anonymous classes in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: Thank you :) This looks like a dire and horrible creation. Should I use it or follow @Jared's advice and avoid it?

Comment: @WindDweller Although anonymous classes can be abused, the feature itself is extremely powerful, and it's definitely not "evil". Lambdas in the new standard greatly reduce the need for anonymous classes that use the old syntax, making the code more readable.

Comment: I think "powerful" is a misleading word.  I don't really object in this instance.  If you just need to ovewrite one method and it's a one-liner (as this is), I agree, creating a separate class file is overkill (although with IDEs like eclipse it's really not that much more of a hassle to just create the class file but it can clutter the package structure and may contribute to spaghetti code).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
String[] stringArr = new String[]{"train", "test"};
```

Does it make any sense now? It is a String array! =) Here's even more stupid code to prove my point:

```
new String[]{"train", "test"}.getClass() == String[].class
```

Answer (score -1):

```
InstanceList[]
```

means that you need to have a list of objects that are of they type InstanceList, same goes for String[]
for these:

```
Object[]
```

means that anything that is a sublass of Object (any object) can be passed as arguments for the last two paramaters.

In the top code this is exactly what they're doing but they create new objects for InstanceList and String,and then labels is the 2 objects they're passing.